# Java8: ambiguity with lambdas and overloaded methods

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I'm playing around with java8 lambdas and I came across a compiler error which I didn't expect.

Say I have a functional `interface A`, an `abstract class B` and a `class C` with overloaded methods that take either `A` or `B` as arguments:

```
public interface A { 
  void invoke(String arg); 
}

public abstract class B { 
  public abstract void invoke(String arg); 
}

public class C {
  public void apply(A x) { }    
  public B apply(B x) { return x; }
}
```

Then I can pass a lambda into `c.apply` and it is correctly resolved to `c.apply(A)`.

```
C c = new C();
c.apply(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

But when I change the overload that takes `B` as argument to a generic version the compiler reports that the two overloads are ambiguous.

```
public class C {
  public void apply(A x) { }    
  public <T extends B> T apply(T x) { return x; }
}
```

I thought the compiler would see that `T` has to be a subclass of `B` which is not a functional interface. Why can't it resolve the correct method?

Comment: You can explicitly call the first method with `c.<A> apply(x -> System.out.println(x));`. But it looks like it should work without it...

Comment: I would guess the answer is that subtype T of B might implement A.

Comment: @user2580516 Yes that could be the problem, I didn't think of that possibility.

Comment: @user2580516 I think you are right and that is an answer. Would you please answer the question properly so it is no longer 'unanswered' and we can vote?

Comment: A subtype T of B might implement A, but it still wouldn't be a functional interface.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23430854/521799

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a lot of complexity at the intersection of overload resolution and type inference. The [current draft](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.9.3.html) of the lambda specification has all the gory details. Sections F and G cover overload resolution and type inference, respectively. I don't pretend to understand it all. The summary sections in the introduction are fairly understandable, though, and I recommend that people read them, particularly the summaries of sections F and G, to get an idea of what's going on in this area.

To recap the issues briefly, consider a method call with some arguments in the presence of overloaded methods. Overload resolution has to choose the right method to call. The "shape" of the method (arity, or number of arguments) is most significant; obviously a method call with one argument can't resolve to a method that takes two parameters. But overloaded methods often have the same number of parameters of different types. In this case, the types start to matter.

Suppose there are two overloaded methods:

```
    void foo(int i);
    void foo(String s);
```

and some code has the following method call:

```
    foo("hello");
```

Obviously this resolves to the second method, based on the type of the argument being passed. But what if we are doing overload resolution, and the argument is a lambda? (Especially one whose types are implicit, that relies on type inference to establish the types.) Recall that a lambda expression's type is inferred from the target type, that is, the type expected in this context. Unfortunately, if we have overloaded methods, we don't have a target type until we've resolved which overloaded method we're going to call. But since we don't yet have a type for the lambda expression, we can't use its type to help us during overload resolution.

Let's look at the example here. Consider interface `A` and abstract class `B` as defined in the example. We have class `C` that contains two overloads, and then some code calls the `apply` method and passes it a lambda:

```
    public void apply(A a)    
    public B apply(B b)

    c.apply(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Both `apply` overloads have the same number of parameters. The argument is a lambda, which must match a functional interface. `A` and `B` are actual types, so it's manifest that `A` is a functional interface whereas `B` is not, therefore the result of overload resolution is `apply(A)`. At this point we now have a target type `A` for the lambda, and type inference for `x` proceeds.

Now the variation:

```
    public void apply(A a)    
    public <T extends B> T apply(T t)

    c.apply(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Instead of an actual type, the second overload of `apply` is a generic type variable `T`. We haven't done type inference, so we don't take `T` into account, at least not until after overload resolution has completed. Thus both overloads are still applicable, neither is most specific, and the compiler emits an error that the call is ambiguous.

You might argue that, since we *know* that `T` has a type bound of `B`, which is a class, not a functional interface, the lambda can't possibly apply to this overload, thus it should be ruled out during overload resolution, removing the ambiguity. I'm not the one to have that argument with. :-) This might indeed be a bug in either the compiler or perhaps even in the specification.

I do know that this area went through a bunch of changes during the design of Java 8. Earlier variations did attempt to bring more type checking and inference information into the overload resolution phase, but they were harder to implement, specify, and understand. (Yes, even harder to understand than it is now.) Unfortunately problems kept arising. It was decided to simplify things by reducing the range of things that can be overloaded.

> Type inference and overloading are ever in opposition; many languages with type inference from day 1 prohibit overloading (except maybe on arity.)  So for constructs like implicit lambdas, which require inference, it seems reasonable to give up something in overloading power to increase the range of cases where implicit lambdas can be used.

-- [Brian Goetz, Lambda Expert Group, 9 Aug 2013](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-spec-experts/2013-August/000340.html)

(This was quite a controversial decision. Note that there were 116 messages in this thread, and there are several other threads that discuss this issue.)

One of the consequences of this decision was that certain APIs had to be changed to avoid overloading, for example, [the Comparator API](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-August/002206.html). Previously, the `Comparator.comparing` method had four overloads:

```
    comparing(Function)
    comparing(ToDoubleFunction)
    comparing(ToIntFunction)
    comparing(ToLongFunction)
```

The problem was that these overloads are differentiated only by the lambda return type, and we actually never quite got the type inference to work here with implicitly-typed lambdas. In order to use these one would always have to cast or supply an explicit type argument for the lambda. These APIs were later changed to:

```
    comparing(Function)
    comparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction)
    comparingInt(ToIntFunction)
    comparingLong(ToLongFunction)
```

which is somewhat clumsy, but it's entirely unambiguous. A similar situation occurs with `Stream.map`, `mapToDouble`, `mapToInt`, and `mapToLong`, and in a few other places around the API.

The bottom line is that getting overload resolution right in the presence of type inference is very difficult in general, and that the language and compiler designers traded away power from overload resolution in order to make type inference work better. For this reason, the Java 8 APIs avoid overloaded methods where implicitly typed lambdas are expected to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. Can I summarize as follows: The bounds of type arguments of generic methods are not taken into account by overload resolution when an implicit typed lambda expression is passed as argument?

Comment: I think that's fair. To expand it a bit, there is a lot of information that's not taken into account during overload resolution.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is that a subtype T of B might implement A, thus making it ambiguous which function to dispatch to for an argument of such a type T.

Comment: As @StuartMarks has commented a subtype of B that implements A is not a functional interface. The compiler reports an error when I try to pass a lambda to a method parameterized with such a type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this test case exposes a situation in which the javac 8 compiler could do more to try to discard an inapplicable overloading candidate, second method in:

```
public class C {
    public void apply(A x) { }    
    public <T extends B> T apply(T x) { return x; }
}
```

Based on the fact that T can never be instantiated to a functional interface. This case is very interesting. @schenka7 thanks for asking this. I will investigate the pros and cons of such a proposal.

Right now the main argument against implementing this could be how frequent this code may be. I guess that once people start converting current Java code to Java 8 the possibilities to find this pattern may be higher.

Another consideration is that if we start adding special cases to the spec / compiler it can get trickier to understand, explain and maintain.

I have filed this bug report: [JDK-8046045](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046045)