# ThrowableCaptor works in Eclipse but not Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, lambda, java-8

To catch exceptions (even on constructors) in my tests elegantly I found the following solution in a blog and used it in all my projects on eclipse:

```
Throwable t= ThrowableCaptor.captureThrowable(() -> (new LinkedList<Object>()));
```

The ThrowableCaptor is implemented by a functional interface and some small extra code:

```
public class ThrowableCaptor {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Actor {
        void act() throws Throwable;
    }

    public static Throwable captureThrowable(final Actor actor) {
        Throwable result = null;
        try {
            actor.act();
        }
        catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            result = throwable;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, as I said, in Eclipse the thing worked like a charm. However under Netbeans I always get the following error message:

```
incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
LinkedList<Object> cannot be converted to void
```

Well, I have no clue, what is wrong...

**Update 1**
After some research I stumbled upon this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398734

I am not sure if it is related, but to my understanding, it suggests a problem with eclipse. Thus my code should indeed be the problem.

I assume, that the problem is matching `new LinkedList<Object>` to `void act() throws Throwable`. I"ll try generics as a solution.

**Update 2**
No Generics in Functional Interfaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made unnecessary work; it is not necessary to create two interfaces and `captureThrowable` methods. All you need is an understanding between Java *Expressions* and *[Expression Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)*. The latter is an expression that is also allowed where a *Statement* is expected. `new` expressions are of the *Expression Statement* category while expressions put into braces are not.

In other words, all you had to do with your original statement:

```
Throwable t= ThrowableCaptor.captureThrowable(() -> (new LinkedList<Object>()));
```

is to remove the braces around `new` expression:

```
Throwable t= ThrowableCaptor.captureThrowable(() -> new LinkedList<Object>());
```

Note that you can further remove the unnecessary type arguments here:

```
Throwable t= ThrowableCaptor.captureThrowable(() -> (new LinkedList<>()));
```

or use a method reference:

```
Throwable t= ThrowableCaptor.captureThrowable(LinkedList::new);
```

---

Side notes:

- An earlier version of  `javac` had the bug of accepting braced expression in wrong contexts as well, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24146285/2711488)
- If you had initially tagged your question with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you had received an answer much earlier

Comment: Thanks for that answer. With that, I learned 3 things: 1) expressions vs. expression statements, 2) make my code much more readable 3) the java-8 tag. I made your answer the new solution, as it obviously is better than what I found.

Answer (score 0):

One can match to Actor only, when a method with return type `void` is called. Changing the return type to `Object` will allow all methods *except* those returning `void`. Therefore, the `ThrowableCaptor` needs a small upgrade, handling both cases by using two distinct functional interfaces. Looks to me like code duplication, but I don't see a nice way around it:

```
public class ThrowableCaptor {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Actor {
        Object act() throws Throwable;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface VoidActor {
        void act() throws Throwable;
    }

    public static Throwable captureThrowable(final Actor actor) {
        Throwable result = null;
        try {
            actor.act();
        }
        catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            result = throwable;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Throwable captureThrowable(final VoidActor actor) {
        Throwable result = null;
        try {
            actor.act();
        }
        catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            result = throwable;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```