# Why does a Java Lambda which throws a Runtime Exception require brackets?

Tags: java, lambda, exception, java-8

I understand that a lambda in java cannot throw a checked exception, but can throw a RuntimeException, but why does the below code require brackets?

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
Integer integer = m.computeIfAbsent("", s -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("fail");});
```

Why can't you have?

```
m.computeIfAbsent("", s -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("fail"));
```

Is it due to the assumption of the compiler that it would return in this instance an int, so therefor can't have a return of an exception, even though its thrown?

Comment: basically, the `s->expr` form only works for expressions. `throw` is a statement.

Comment: ah, this makes sense, if you put it in an answer I will put it as the marked answer

Comment: You may also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41482574/2711488) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24146285/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger cool, I did have a look for other questions, but I guess I was a bit more specific as to what I was looking at.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [describes the body of a lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)

> A lambda body is either a single expression or a block (§14.2).

This, however,

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("fail")
```

is the [`throw` *statement*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18), not an expression. The compiler therefore rejects it as the lambda expression's body.

You can go down the rabbit hole and learn what all the types of expressions are, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression) (follow the grammar).

Comment: +1. Confusingly enough, when you put an unbracketed `throw` statement into a lambda, `javac` gives the error `illegal start of expression` at the `throw`.