# Efficient way in java8 stream to download file

Tags: java, file, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have few string values and on basis of that string I need to download few files. What will be most efficient way of doing this in java8.

```
List<String> keyValues = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3","key4");
keyValues.stream().forEach(i -> (FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(urlStr + i), new File(filePath + i))) );
```

forEach is giving error as " is not applicable for the arguments (( i) -> {})"

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24147329/2711488). But note that even after fixing the syntax, it won’t work, if `copyURLToFile` declares checked exceptions.

Comment: try enabling stream().parallel() - looks like the task might be IO intensive so could possibly benefit from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its interesting but puting that one line into function and calling that function from lambda works fine..Refer blog : http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/06/lambdas-are-glue-code.html

```
operatorKeys.forEach(i ->  downloadFile(i));
```

Obviously surround with proper try/catch bloacks..

Comment: If you do that, you can use a method reference instead: `forEach(this::download)`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets from around your lambda:

```
keyValues.forEach(i -> FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(urlStr + i), new File(filePath + i)));
```

My guess is the brackets around the call are confusing the compiler into thinking you have a function instead of a consumer.

Note also that you don't need the call to `stream()`; you can invoke `.forEach()` directly from Collections.

Comment: The compiler isn’t confused, an expression in parentheses is always an expression, not a statement. So it can’t be a consumer. The `param -> methodInvocation` form works, because the invocation is both, a statement and an expression. So the compiler is strictly following the rules. The invalidity of bracketed expression is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24147329/2711488), the valid expression statements can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41483237/2711488).

Comment: @Holger "confused" was a turn of phrase. Of course an inanimate determinant program can't be confused.   Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Thanks Holger and Bohemian for your explanation but nothing works. I then refer http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/06/lambdas-are-glue-code.html and try to put that one line inside function and called function within lamda.. that worked.

Comment: Try wrapping in curly brackets and add a semicolon. Ie `i -> {...;}`