# Why do Consumers accept lambdas with statement bodies but not expression bodies?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-inference

The following code surprisingly is compiling successfully:

```
Consumer<String> p = ""::equals;
```

This too:

```
p = s -> "".equals(s);
```

But this is fails with the error `boolean cannot be converted to void` as expected:

```
p = s -> true;
```

Modification of the second example with parenthesis also fails:

```
p = s -> ("".equals(s));
```

Is it a bug in Java compiler or is there a type inference rule I don't know about?

Comment: Eclipse complains as well, so probably *not* a compiler bug.

Comment: `s -> true;` and `s -> ("".equals(s))` is interpreted as `s -> {return true;}` or `s -> { return ("".equals(s));}` And they are not a `Function<String, Boolean>`. `p = s -> true;` this no make sense, use `p = s -> {};` instead.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I understand why last two lines of code are not compiling. It is not clear as the second two works.

Comment: @Zefick IMHO it's a license of compiler, It must interpret you can ignore the return value. to avoid unnecessary verbosity, if It don't do that, you can't use `p = ""::equals;` and you must to define `p = s -> "".equals(s);` as this: `p = s -> {"".equals(s);};`. IMHO It's a good decision.

Comment: See [Why does a Java method reference with return type match the Consumer interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37308294/2711488) or [Lambda 'special void-compatibility rule' - statement expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41482574/2711488). Regarding, why round brackets change the behavior, see [Java 8 Lambda Syntax change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24147329/2711488)…

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First, it's worth looking at what a `Consumer<String>` actually is. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

> Represents an operation that **accepts a single input argument and
>   returns no result**. Unlike most other functional interfaces, Consumer
>   is expected to operate via side-effects.

So it's a function that accepts a String and returns nothing.

```
Consumer<String> p = ""::equals;
```

Compiles successfully because `equals` can take a String (and, indeed, any Object). The result of equals is just ignored.*

```
p = s -> "".equals(s);
```

This is exactly the same, but with different syntax. The compiler knows not to add an implicit `return` because a `Consumer` should not return a value. It *would* add an implicit `return` if the lambda was a `Function<String, Boolean>` though.

```
p = s -> true;
```

This takes a String (`s`) but because `true` is an expression and not a statement, the result cannot be ignored in the same way. The compiler *has to* add an implicit `return` because an expression can't exist on its own. Thus, this *does* have a return: a boolean. Therefore it's not a `Consumer`.**

```
p = s -> ("".equals(s));
```

Again, this is an *expression*, not a statement. Ignoring lambdas for a moment, you will see the line `System.out.println("Hello");` will similarly fail to compile if you wrap it in parentheses.

---

*From [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaBody):

> If the body of a lambda is a statement expression (that is, an expression that would be allowed to stand alone as a statement), it is compatible with a void-producing function type; any result is simply discarded.

**From [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) (thanks, [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene)):

> A lambda expression is congruent with a [void-producing] function type if ...
>   the lambda body is either a statement expression
>   ([§14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8))
>   or a void-compatible block.

Comment: So the key moment is that result of `equals` can be just ignored. Quite unexpectedly for such strong typed language.

Comment: @Zefick Yes, the key difference is that statements may or may not have an implicit `return` (based on inference), while expressions always have an implicit `return`. It results in nicer syntax.

Comment: @Michael Someday I would love to know *why* there is a distinction between statements and expressions in the language. I really don't get it, just let everything be statements...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's not a compiler that defines this, but JLS :) (to which compilers have to conform). If all expressions where statements compilers wouldn't be able to report a lot of errors. If all results from non-void functions would have to be used, lots of unnecessary assignments / additional local variables would be needed, just think of `StringBuilder.append(..)` for a start. It's been like this for a long time, possibly since Java 1.0

Answer (score 12):

I think the other answers complicate the explanation by focusing on lambdas whereas their behavior in this case is similar to the behavior of manually implemented methods. This compiles:

```
new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(final String s) {
        "".equals(s);
    }
}
```

whereas this does not:

```
new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(final String s) {
        true;
    }
}
```

because `"".equals(s)` is a statement but `true` is not. A lambda expression for a functional interface returning void requires a statement so it follows the same rules as a method's body.

Note that in general lambda bodies don't follow *exactly* the same rules as method bodies - in particular, if a lambda whose body is an expression implements a method returning a value, it has an implicit `return`. So for example, `x -> true` would be a valid implementation of `Function<Object, Boolean>`, whereas `true;` is not a valid method body. But in this particular case functional interfaces and method bodies coincide.

Comment: "there is nothing special about lambdas here". You're mostly right, however `s -> "".equals(s)` can satisfy both `Consumer<String>` **and** `Function<String, Boolean>` which I believe was a source of the confusion.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that `s -> true` *can* be a valid lambda (e.g. `Predicate<String> foo = s -> true;`) whereas `true;` on its own will never compile.

Answer (score 8):

```
s -> "".equals(s)
```

and

```
s -> true
```

don't rely on same function descriptors.

`s -> "".equals(s)` may refer either `String->void` or `String->boolean` function descriptor.
`s -> true` refers to only `String->boolean` function descriptor.

Why ?

- when you write `s -> "".equals(s)`, the body of the lambda : `"".equals(s)` **is a statement that produces a value**.
  The compiler considers that the function may return either `void` or  `boolean`.

So writing :

```
Function<String, Boolean> function = s -> "".equals(s);
Consumer<String> consumer = s -> "".equals(s);
```

is valid.

When you assign the lambda body to a `Consumer<String>` declared variable, the descriptor `String->void` is used.
Of course, this code doesn't make much sense (you check the equality and you don't use the result) but the compiler doesn't care.
It is the same thing when you write a statement : `myObject.getMyProperty()` where `getMyProperty()` returns a `boolean` value but that you don't store the result of it.

- when you write `s -> true`, the body of the lambda : `true` **is a single expression** .
  The compiler considers that the function returns **necessarily**  `boolean`.
  So only the descriptor `String->boolean` may be used.

---

Now, come back to your code that doesn't compile.
What are you trying to do ?

```
Consumer<String> p = s -> true;
```

You cannot. You want to assign to a variable that uses the function descriptor  `Consumer<String>` a lambda body with the `String->void` function descriptor.
It doesn't match !

Comment: I actually think `s -> "".equals(s)` is a *statement expression* according to the JLS - that means an expression is allowed to be used as a statement.

Comment: here is the link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8