# Ambiguous method call with Lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, assertj

I have defined a static `assertThat` method to extend AssertJ. This method accepts a lambda expression of the type:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Action {
  void execute() throws Exception;
}
```

The signature looks like this:

```
public static ExceptionAssert assertThat(Action action)
```

I want to use this method with a static import. But it is ambiguous. The compiler doesn't know whether [assertThat(Iterable)](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.java#L194) or my method should be used. I don't understand how a `void` method can conflict with a method that returns an `Iterator<T>`.

Any idea how to resolve this conflict (without writing the class name in front of `assertThat`)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should specify the type of lambda explicitly:

```
assertThat((Action)() -> {
    ...
});
```

The other option is just using the other name, for example, `assertNoException`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how a `void` method can conflict with a method that returns an `Iterator<T>`.

The only way you can have such a conflict is when your lambda expression never completes normally, e.g. `()->{ throw new RuntimeException(); }` or `()->{ for(;;); }`.

(or if your lambda expression consist of a single method invocation which indeed returns an `Iterable`)

For all other cases you are right, there shouldn’t be such a conflict and, indeed I could compile equivalent code without any problems with `jdk1.8.0_20` for ordinary lambda expressions (you didn’t include the code which triggers the error in your question).

If you experienced the problem with a lambda expression which can complete normally and have used an older jdk, you ran into the bug discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23430854/2711488). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23431672/2711488) refers to the language specification part specifying the difference between `void`-compatible and value-compatible lambda expressions.

If you used a different compiler or IDE, e.g. Eclipse, make sure you are using the most recent version and file a bug report, if this error still occurs.

Comment: It is actually the problem that the code throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse version 4.4.1
Upgrading to 4.4.2 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem and as brafdlog suggested upgrading to a newer version of eclipse fixed it. Except in my case I was already on 4.4.2 (Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4) and upgraded to the latest Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 fixed it.