# java 8 lambda ambiguous runnable and callback

Tags: java, java-8

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).submit(() -> {doSmth();});
```

"Ambiguous method call. Both submit (Callable) in ExecutorService and submit (Runnable) in ExecutorService match."

How to fix it? I know that I can use anonymous class but I'd like to use Function.

Comment: Works at my IDE (IntelliJ) w/o a problem. Furthermore, if `doSmth` is an instance method, you can rewrite this as `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).submit(this::doSmth);`

Comment: What IDE/compiler? Are you sure your lambda has a block body? (`{doSmth();}` and not `doSmth()`.) Could be a bug.

Comment: Check whether this is your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23430854/2711488

Comment: Works on Eclipse too, no compilation errors.

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the linked duplicate, since that was a JDK bug, and this is a "resolve ambiguity" issue...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).submit(() -> 1); //Callable
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).submit(() -> {doSmth();}); //Runnable
```

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).submit(()-> 1);` is sufficient for the Callable.

Answer (score 3):

In ambiguous cases explicitly provide the type:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {doSmth();}
submit(runnable);
//or:
submit((Runnable) () -> {doSmth();});
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, though. The OP has a block body so for it to be a `Callable` it needs to explicitly return a value.