# Java 8 Consumer/Function Lambda Ambiguity

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, overloading, jls

I have an overloaded method that takes a Consumer and a Function object respectively and returns a generic type that matches the corresponding Consumer/Function. I thought this would be fine, but when I try to call either method with a lambda expression I get an error indicating the reference to the method is ambiguous.

Based on my reading of [JLS §15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1) it seems like the compiler should know that my lambda with a void block matches the Consumer method and my lambda with a return type matches the Function method.

I put together the following sample code that fails to compile:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class AmbiguityBug {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    doStuff(getPattern(x -> System.out.println(x)));
    doStuff(getPattern(x -> String.valueOf(x)));
  }

  static Pattern<String, String> getPattern(Function<String, String> function) {
    return new Pattern<>(function);
  }

  static ConsumablePattern<String> getPattern(Consumer<String> consumer) {
    return new ConsumablePattern<>(consumer);
  }

  static void doStuff(Pattern<String, String> pattern) {
    String result = pattern.apply("Hello World");
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  static void doStuff(ConsumablePattern<String> consumablePattern) {
    consumablePattern.consume("Hello World");
  }

  public static class Pattern<T, R> {
    private final Function<T, R> function;

    public Pattern(Function<T, R> function) {
      this.function = function;
    }

    public R apply(T value) {
      return function.apply(value);
    }
  }

  public static class ConsumablePattern<T> {
    private final Consumer<T> consumer;

    public ConsumablePattern(Consumer<T> consumer) {
      this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void consume(T value) {
      consumer.accept(value);
    }
  }
}
```

I also found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430854/lambda-expression-and-method-overloading-doubts) stackoverflow post that turned out to be a compiler bug. My case is very similar, though a bit more complicated. To me this still looks like a bug, but I wanted to make sure I am not misunderstanding the language spec for lambdas. I'm using Java 8u45 which should have all of the latest fixes.

If I change my method calls to be wrapped in a block everything seems to compile, but this adds additional verbosity and many auto-formatters will reformat it into multiple lines.

```
doStuff(getPattern(x -> { System.out.println(x); }));
doStuff(getPattern(x -> { return String.valueOf(x); }));
```

Comment: The getPattern calls that (should) use the Consumer are both missing a right parenthesis (I can't edit this in because of the minimum character limit).

Comment: Another work-around is to specify the type of x: `doStuff(getPattern((String x) -> System.out.println(x)));` `doStuff(getPattern((String x) -> String.valueOf(x)));`

Comment: @Misha: that's actually seems strange for me. I have no reasonable explanation why adding the `x` type changes the things. Would you expect that this case will map to the `Function`: `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();getPattern((String x) -> map.remove(x));`?

Comment: @TagirValeev See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5-310.  There are special rules for determining "more specific" relationship between functional interface types if lambda is explicitly typed.  Under those rules, `Function` appears to be more specific than `Consumer`

Comment: You may use `x -> (String.valueOf(x))` to call the `Function` based method and 
 `x->{String.valueOf(x);}` to call the `Consumer` based method. But given the fact that these methods do completely different things and produce differently typed results which cause another overload selection of methods which again do entirely different things, using the same names for these methods is a horrible disguise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This line is definitely ambiguous:

```
doStuff(getPattern(x -> String.valueOf(x)));
```

Reread this from the linked JLS chapter:

> A lambda expression (§15.27) is potentially compatible with a functional interface type (§9.8) if all of the following are true:
>
> - The arity of the target type's function type is the same as the arity of the lambda expression.
> - If the target type's function type has a void return, then the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block (§15.27.2).
> - If the target type's function type has a (non-void) return type, then the lambda body is either an expression or a value-compatible block (§15.27.2).

In your case for `Consumer` you have a [statement expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) as any method invocation can be used as statement expression even if the method is non-void. For example, you can simply write this:

```
public void test(Object x) {
    String.valueOf(x);
}
```

It makes no sense, but compiles perfectly. Your method may have a side-effect, compiler doesn't know about it. For example, were it `List.add` which always returns `true` and nobody cares about its return value.

Of course this lambda also qualifies for `Function` as it's an expression. Thus it's ambigue. If you have something which is an expression, but not a *statement expression*, then the call will be mapped to `Function` without any problem:

```
doStuff(getPattern(x -> x == null ? "" : String.valueOf(x)));
```

When you change it to `{ return String.valueOf(x); }`, you create a [value-compatible block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2), so it matches the `Function`, but it does not qualify as a *void-compatible block*. However you may have problems with blocks as well:

```
doStuff(getPattern(x -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}));
```

This block qualifies both as a value-compatible and a void-compatible, thus you have an ambiguity again. Another ambigue block example is an endless loop:

```
doStuff(getPattern(x -> {while(true) System.out.println(x);}));
```

As for `System.out.println(x)` case it's a little bit tricky. It surely qualifies as *statement expression*, so can be matched to `Consumer`, but seems that it matches to expression as well as spec says that [method invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) is an expression. However it's an expression of limited use [like 15.12.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3) says:

> If the compile-time declaration is void, then the method invocation must be a top level expression (that is, the Expression in an expression statement or in the ForInit or ForUpdate part of a for statement), or a compile-time error occurs. Such a method invocation produces no value and so must be used only in a situation where a value is not needed.

So compiler perfectly follows the specification. First it determines that your lambda body is qualified both as an expression (even though its return type is void: 15.12.2.1 makes no exception for this case) and a statement expression, so it's considered an ambiguity as well.

Thus for me both statements compile according to the specification. ECJ compiler produces the same error messages on this code.

In general I'd suggest you to avoid overloading your methods when your overloads has the same number of parameters and has the difference only in accepted functional interface. Even if these functional interfaces have different arity (for example, `Consumer` and `BiConsumer`): you will have no problems with lambda, but may have problems with method references. Just select different names for your methods in this case (for example, `processStuff` and `consumeStuff`).

Comment: Why such ambiguity arises between `Consumer<A>` and `Function<A, B>`, but doesn't arise between `Runner` and `Supplier<B>`?

Comment: I.e. `cf(i -> Math.abs(i))` (where `cf` is defined for both `Consumer<A>` and `Function<A, B>`) arises ambiguity, but `rs(() -> Math.abs(0))` (where `rs` is defined for both `Runner` and `Supplier<B>`) doesn't.

Comment: @Sasha because _"The arity of the target type's function type is the same as the arity of the lambda expression"._ In your case this type is `A`. Return type `B` out of analysis scope.

Comment: @Woland, don't `Supplier<B>` and `Runnable` have the same arity?

Comment: @Sasha Supplier `**T** get()`, Runnable `**void** run()`. So, return type has impact on overloading in case of `@FunctionalInterface`.

Comment: @Woland, Function `**R** apply(T t)`, Consumer `**void** accept(T t)` — so?