# Interesting behaviour in Java Lambda expression in polymorphism

Tags: java, lambda, polymorphism

I found an interesting behavior when using polymorphism in Java lambda expr.
I hope someone could shed some light on this.

Assume following things:

```
public class Java8Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a  = new B();
        a.meth((z) -> System.out.println() );
    }
}

interface X
{
    void meth(int a);
}

interface Y
{
    void meth(int a);
}

class A
{
    void meth(X x)
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}

class B extends A
{
    void meth(X x)
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

If you run Java8Test.main , we get output as

> B

We know the "a" refers to B's reference at runtime and so it prints "B"
But when we change the method type in Class B as follows

```
    class B extends A
{
    void meth(Y y)
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

If you run Java8Test.main , we get output as

> A

We know the "a" refers to B's reference at runtime BUT , how come it prints "A" this time ??

Answer (score 3):

The lambda expression is a red-herring. When you change the method signature in class B, it's no longer overriding the

```
void meth(X x)
```

method in class A.

Comment: 1. Dont you think the lamda signature matches on class B meth() as well ?
2. Moreover, it is B's reference is at runtime not A

Comment: This just shows that you should always use @Override:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 1):

> In both cases, `meth()` version of `B` class is being invoked.

In first case, **Overridden** `meth()` is invoked and in second case **Inherited** `meth()` is invoked.

As you are extending `A` class, `meth(X x)` method will be inherited from parent and `meth(X x)` and `meth(Y y)` two distinct methods are present in child `B` class.

PS : Type of lambda expression is of **Target type**.

Useful article to understand type of lambda :

1. [Target typing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing)
2. [Java 8 Lambda expressions](http://java8.in/java-8-lambda-expression/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to how overloaded methods are resolved with lambda expressions.
Here is a somewhat similar question with a very detailed answer: [Java8: ambiguity with lambdas and overloaded methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905169/java8-ambiguity-with-lambdas-and-overloaded-methods)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following happen. When you implement:

```
void meth(Y y) {
    System.out.println("B");
}
```

by class `B`, this method does not override:

```
void meth(X x) {
    System.out.println("A");
}
```

of class A. But the variable:

```
A a  = new B();
```

is of type `A` and hence the statement:

```
a.meth((z) -> System.out.println());
```

does refere to `A`s method, which consequently will print **A**.