# Understanding adding a ChangeListener in TableView

Tags: java, tableview, changelistener

I am trying to understand some code from the following source:

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part3/

The specific line i am still curious about is the following one:

```
personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue));
```

I believe that my first understanding of the javadoc was not correct; especially on this part (`[...].selectedItemProperty().[...]`):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty--

I was asking myself why we are only adding one listener while we may have several dataobjects but now my understanding is the following and it would be nice to know if it is correct:

What the doc means is that "selectedItem" itself is the property (not the underlying data!)which represents a row that is selected/selection-changed at runtime, so the change method of our Listener is then evoked when the user changes the selected row. Then the synchronization with the underlying datamodel takes place via the `change(...)` method of the `ChangeListener` Interface, which gets the corresponding dataobjects from the udnerlying datamodel to work on. So from my understanding i would probably raise an exception if i didn't do a correct `setItems(...)` on my TableView.

Is this correct so far?

If yes, i have got a follow up question: `ReadOnlyObjectProperty` implements both `Observable` and `ObservableValue` which both have the method `addListener`. Is it correct that the Lambda-Expression is resolved correctly by checking the list of parameters of the two methods of the two possible functional interfaces which could be argument to either one of the `addListener(...)` methods? That point seemd rather complex to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`selectionModel.selectedItemProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) is a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<T>` where `T` is the type of elements in the [item list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#itemsProperty) backing your `TableView<T>`.  Whenever a new item is selected in the TableView, the value of the selectedItemProperty changes to refer to the new item.  The selected item itself is not a `TableRow<T>`, it just a reference to the underlying data item which is used render the row.  In general, you, as an application programmer, usually don't care about the TableRow which is a visual construct, but only the underlying data.  When the user clicks on a row in the table, the TableView implementation sets the selectedItemProperty to the selected data item, that in turn fires any change listeners which have been set on the property.

In the case of the makery example, the `T` type is `Person`.  So the consequence of this line:

```
personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue)
);
```

is to invoke the `showPersonDetails(Person person)` function, passing in the selected person whenever that changes.

> So from my understanding i would probably raise an exception if i didn't do a correct setItems(...) on my TableView.

No. If you didn't set any items, the user could never select an item on the table, so you wouldn't ever get an exception from the selected item change listener as the selected item would never change from null and the change listener would never fire.

> i have got a follow up question: ReadOnlyObjectProperty implements both Observable and ObservableValue which both have the method addListener. Is it correct that the Lambda-Expression is resolved correctly by checking the list of parameters of the two methods of the two possible functional interfaces which could be argument to either one of the addListener(...) methods?

Yes.  How the lambda resolves which method to use [which is complicated in compiler implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905169/java8-ambiguity-with-lambdas-and-overloaded-methods), but from an application programmer usability point of view, you can just count the parameters: If it is one parameter, then an `InvalidationListener` is being defined, if it is 3 parameters, then a `ChangeListener` is being defined.

There are two `addListener(...)` methods as it is an [overloaded method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), one for a [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) and another for an [InvalidationListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html#addListener-javafx.beans.InvalidationListener-).  The difference between the two is subtle and is [explained by the developer of the interfaces](https://netopyr.com/2012/02/08/when-to-use-a-changelistener-or-an-invalidationlistener/) with the recommendation: "use a ChangeListener if you need to know the new value in the listener, otherwise use an InvalidationListener".

Comment: Sorry i am so very late to reply and many thanks you for clarifying this to me! I obviously didn't think the exception-part of it through till the end as it seems to me now. You say "application programmer usability point of view"; I am not really sure how deep I should dig into this and where it just doesn't make any more sense. Would it at this point considered to be normal for me not to look at the code that handles how the selection and selection-changes are handeled below the "surface" I am at right now?